# ubuntu upstart permission error when writing to log on a non admin user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, logging, upstart

I have a simple upstart script:

```
start on started network-services

respawn
respawn limit 100 5

setuid www-data

exec node /var/testapp/app.js >> /var/log/testapp.log 2>&1

post-start exec echo "Server was (re)started on $(date)" | mail -s "Crashing Server (re)starting" admin@sample-test.com
```

but because I'm running the node app as 'www-data', I don't have write permissions on `testapp.log`.

What is the best approach to address that?

I would rather not pre-create the log file with 'www-data' as it's owner, because I would like as few steps as possible for the setup. I'd also rather not run the app as 'www-data' with sudo:

```
exec sudo -u www-data node /var/testapp/app.js >> /var/log/testapp.log 2>&1
```

because when I do so, root is also running the process. Maybe I'm wrong, but I see that as a security issue. If it's not a security issue - please enlighten me.

Comment: Did you solve it? I have same problem

Comment: @igo - i solved it by running the exec like so:
exec sudo -u www-data node /var/testapp/app.js >> /var/log/testapp.log 2>&1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create another directory in the log dir and give www-data ownership:

```
sudo mkdir /var/log/testapp
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/log/testapp
```

`/var/log/testapp` is now writable by www-data, so then in upstart script you would have:

```
exec node /var/testapp/app.js >> /var/log/testapp/app.log 2>&1
```